# Set Home Launcher via ADB

Tags: android, adb

I want my app to be in KIOSK mode every startup, so in my `AndroidManifest.xml` I define my `MainActivity` as

```
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I am developing in an S99 smart watch. Unfortunately, I couldn't find a setting item where I can customize its default home launcher.
Home launcher selection won't also display when I tap the home menu.

So I am thinking to have it via ADB. Is it possible?

**How can I set my Activity to be the default launcher in ADB**?

Comment: I suppose you have resolved this long ago... If not, I might know for a few ways to resolve this. :)

Comment: @zed share your few ways - it's not just this guy who might want to know.

Comment: Hey @android.weasel, sadly this was a year ago and back then these ways of mine worked, but after the recent update at the start of summer security is quite tightened up and it complicated things. So with this, I am at square one too..